# DB2 z/OS - Get the last 2 digits of year

Tags: sql, db2, substr, db2-zos

```
SELECT
     SUBSTR(CAST(YEAR(SOMEDATE) AS VARCHAR(4)),2,2) AS "YY" 
FROM SOMESCHEMA.FOO;
```

Gets me the following error:

> 1. [Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  ILLEGAL SYMBOL ",2". SOME SYMBOLS
>    THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14
> 2. [Code: -514, SQL State: 26501]  THE CURSOR SQL_CURLH200C1 IS NOT IN
>    A PREPARED STATE. SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, DRIVER=4.26.14

And no matter what I change, the error stays..

Comment: how are you submitting the SQL? From which tool?  Some details missing from question.  If you try with an interactive SQL tool , and adjust the query to replace SOMEDATE by CURRENT DATE (just for testing), and replace the table name by `sysibm.sysdummy1` (just for testing), you may get more details.  Sometimes, what gets executed is not what you assume.

Comment: I use DBVisualizer. Seems unlikely that this simple SQL statement is not executed correctly.

Comment: Does the statement run when submitted via a different non-java tool , for example via odbc or CLI, or directly via ISPF or DB2I, SPUFI  etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for DB2 z/OS is:

```
VARCHAR_FORMAT(SOMEDATE, 'YY') AS "YY"
```